# Unity - Event.current in Editor Window not updating

Tags: c#, window, editor, unity-game-engine

So I'm working on a Custom Editor Window and trying to get when the user has clicked the left mouse button. The problem I'm having is that whenever I click on a GUI element that I have placed, in this case an EditorGUI.Foldout element, the Event.current doesn't get updated. So when I try to check if the user is clicking the left mouse button it does nothing whenever it should be. But if I'm not clicking in that area it detects it!

So my question to you is what exactly am I doing wrong here? I'm collecting the Event.current at the very first line of void OnGUI() and no where else. I'll add in some code snippets that will hopefully help in finding a solution!

Where I call Event.Current:

```
void OnGUI()
{
    Event currentEvent = Event.current;
    ...
}
```

When I'm trying to access Event.Current:

```
void OnGUI()
{
    ...
    Rect baseLabelRect = new Rect();
    baseLabelRect.x = 0;
    baseLabelRect.y = 21;
    baseLabelRect.width = this.position.width;
    baseLabelRect.height = 16;

    if (selected)
        EditorGUI.DrawRect(baseLabelRect, selectedItemColor);

    EditorGUI.indentLevel = 1;

    GUI.contentColor = Color.black;
    GUI.backgroundColor = Color.grey;

    itemListFoldout[0] = EditorGUI.Foldout(baseLabelRect, itemListFoldout[0], "Fouldout test");

    GUI.contentColor = origContentColor;
    GUI.backgroundColor = origBackgroundColor;

    if (currentEvent.button == 0 && currentEvent.isMouse)
    {
        Debug.Log("left mouse button clicked");
        if (baseLabelRect.Contains(currentEvent.mousePosition))
        {
            selected = true;
            Debug.Log("rect clicked");
        }
        else
            selected = false;
    }
}
```

This is where I'm currently having troubles. Whenever I click on the area where the EditorGUI.Foldout is at it should be detected and be setup to be selected. But it doesn't seem to update Event.current whenever I click in the Foldout's area. But it will update if I click anywhere else in the Editor Window.

If you have any idea why this would be happening I would love to hear your ideas! Any and all help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Another way do detect someone clicking the left mouse button is with the Input.GetKeyDown function within the Update function, like so:

```
void Update(){
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)){
        Debug.Log("Left mouse button clicked.");
    }
}
```

I hope this is helpful!